# Выберите предпочтительный с точки зрения стиля вариант фразы:

Tags: стилистика

Выберите предпочтительный с точки зрения стиля вариант фразы:

В разделе Выполнить действие выберите действие, которое будет выполняться для отфильтрованных писем.

В разделе Выполнить действие выберите, каким образом нужно обрабатывать отфильтрованные письма.

В разделе Выполнить действие выберите способ обработки отфильтрованных писем. +?

В разделе Выполнить действие выберите способ обработки писем, отфильтрованных ранее.

Comment: Не знаю насчет стиля, но первый вариант самый четкий. Я бы предпочел читать четкую и ясную инструкцию, а не стильную мешанину.

Answer (score 0):

В разделе ВЫПОЛНИТЬ ДЕЙСТВИЕ выберите тип обработки отфильтрованных писем.

В разделе «Выполнить действие» задайте вид обработки отфильтрованных писем.